# Flatten Sequence With Boolean Expression Generator

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am looking for a generator that will flatten a sequence of tuples based on a Boolean expression. My data looks like this:

```
my_data = ((3, 4), (None, 4), (5, 8), (None, 1), (None, 9)...)
```

What I'd like to do is to flatten this into a one dimensional generator of numbers where I take the first item in each tuple if it is not `None`, otherwise take the second item. My result would yield the following sequence:

```
3, 4, 5, 1, 9...
```

I am thinking the easiest way to do this would be to use a Boolean expression with short circuiting, but I can't seem to compose a proper generator. I realize I could define a generator function and this would be fairly straightforward, but I'm curious if this can be done with a comprehension?

My attempt:

```
(x or y for subitem in my_data for x, y in subitem)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll need to check for `None` explicitly, or a tuple like `(0, None)` or `(0, 1)` will trip you up:

```
(x if x is not None else y for x,y in my_data)
```

Example:

```
>>> my_data = ((3, 4), (None, 4), (5, 8), (None, 1), (0, None), (0, 1))
>>> [x or y for x,y in my_data]
[3, 4, 5, 1, None, 1]
>>> [x if x is not None else y for x,y in my_data]
[3, 4, 5, 1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: For my use case a value is only available when it is non-zero, otherwise it is none, but great point. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 7):

```
(x[0] or x[1] for x in my_data)
```

or alternatively,

```
(x or y for x,y in my_data)
```

Comment: This fails on `my_data = ((3, 4), (None, 4), (5, 8), (None, 1), (0, None))`.

Comment: Patrick has since clarified that there will never be a zero in the first position of the tuple, so my point is moot. I just can't upvote your answer yet - I've used up all my votes for today...